# Xslt for a XML with no parent tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag>Funny</tag>
<tag>Hilarious</tag>
<tag>Stupid</tag>
```

I am having difficulty constructing a XSLT file without a parent node. Is it possible to do this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
 >
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/" >
<body>
  <xsl:apply-templates select ="tags/tag"/>
</body>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tag" >
  <li>
  <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      album.aspx/<xsl:value-of select="."  />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </a>
 </li>
```

I have to enclose my xml with XML for this xslt to work.

Comment: You don't have "a simple XML file", you have a text file that is not XML.  To be an XML document it _must_ have a single root-level element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Processor always search for well-formed XML document. You must make your XML well-formed before applying any XSLT on it.